# Is it possible to make a discord.py bot mute a channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command that mutes a text channel you're in. I just need to know if the discord.py library has something for that. Like mute the channel so you don't get any notifications from it.

Comment: Basically Muting a Text Channels? Are you making a userbot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of sounds are you trying to mute?  If you are joining a text channel, you shouldn't be getting voices or broadcasting to it.

You might find this useful, though `channel` is a voice channel:

`await change_voice_state(*, channel, self_mute=False, self_deaf=False)`

```
This function is a coroutine.

Changes client’s voice state in the guild.
```

I haven't used discord.py so pardon syntax/use errors.

If you mean that you want the audio to be muted when you join a text channel, maybe something like:

```
if discord.channelType == text:
    discord.VoiceState.self_deaf = true;
```

If you want it to mute the microphone instead of the speakers, though if you are in just a text channel that this is necessary:

```
    discord.VoiceState.self_mute = true;
```

These are assuming that the bot is controlling the current user.

Otherwise, browse the discord.py documentation (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20voicestate#) to see if you can find something that suits your exact needs better.

Comment: I mean like, not voice channels. Text channels, mute them so you don't receive notifications. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough. I've been browsing but I didn't manage to find anything in the discord documentation. I came to stack to verify my question

Comment: I don't know what guild permissions are or if you have them, but what about this:


class discord.NotificationLevel

    Specifies whether a Guild has notifications on for all messages or mentions only by default.

    all_messages

        Members receive notifications for every message regardless of them being mentioned.

    only_mentions

        Members receive notifications for messages they are mentioned in.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`TextChannel.set_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions)

`await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.author, send_messages=False)`

This should work and it will remove permissions of the person who typed the command to send messages.

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly what I want. However, this is pretty useful. Thanks. Basically my mute command is supposed to be for channels. Mute it so that I wouldn't receive any more notifications from it.